# Xcode showing use of undeclared type on CoreData classes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I'm having an issue with Xcode where all usages of my CoreData classes show `Use of undeclared type [class name]`. The project builds and runs correctly, but all instances where I reference my CoreData classes get the red warning highlighting in Xcode and none of the code completion works. Has anyone else run into this issue? Here's what I've tried:

- Delete derived data
- Clean
- Clean build folder
- Delete Archives (Developer/Xcode/Archives)
- Delete Products (Developer/Xcode/Products)
- Remove and re-add the xcdatamodeld file
- Restart Xcode
- Restart my Mac

I am using Xcode 9.4.1 (using beta versions of 10 is not an option) and have run out of ideas. The codebase is written in Swift 4. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's something to do with CoreData's code generation. Previously, turning the codegen to None then changing it back to Class Definitions worked. Seems like that is no longer resolving the issue for me. I had all of my entities set to generate class definitions:

[image]

After I changed this to Manual and generated my classes manually, things are working as expected.

1. Change this setting to Manual/None
2. Generate the classes manually (Editor > Create NSManagedObject Subclass... > Select Your Model > Select All Entities)
3. Delete the derived data folder